# Will clicking on Google document mistakenly from other students in a class that I did not enroll in can be considered as academic misconduct?

Tags: ethics, personal-misconduct

I'm a visiting student in a public university in Idiana.
Last Feburary, March and May, a student from another class shared with me a Google document multiple times:

- a group work from a course which I did not enroll in
- which gave me the permission to edit the document.

However, I did not change anything as any change will be recorded in the google drive document editing history.
I just clicked on the link for curiousity.

- Will I be in trouble with the Dean of the student on academic misconduct?
- What should I do in this case as the grade for that course has been posted and I did not see any communication from university official?

Comment: I think you're missing something because none of this post makes any sense.

Comment: What I'm missing?

Comment: Why you think opening a document is misconduct, why you expect a grade in a course you're not enrolled in, why you're expecting a university official to communicate with you, why it matters that you have "permission to edit" the document, why it would matter whether or not you changed anything in the document, etc.

Comment: Yeah I forgot as I checked this policy and I'm quite worry: A student must not steal, change, destroy, or impede another student’s work, nor should the student unjustly attempt, through a bribe, a promise of favors or threats, to affect any student’s grade or the evaluation of academic performance. Impeding another student’s work includes, but is not limited to, the theft, defacement, or mutilation of resources so as to deprive others of the information they contain.

Comment: Did you do any of the things in that policy? If so, which one?

Comment: I asked my friend about it and he told me that: accessing a Google document for a course in which you were not enrolled, without proper authorization, can be seen as interference with another student's work. Reviewing the document without permission may be considered interfering with the privacy and integrity of the group work. However, I'm not totally believe in him

Comment: Another student invited you to take a look at their work and you did. That's not remotely an interference.

Comment: Thanks. What should I do in this case? Should I let it go or should I tell to that student ?

Comment: Nothing, really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What people consider to be X or Y is something completely up to them. We here can only talk about the standard of the semi-mythical "*reasonable*" person.

Looking at a document cannot constitute academic misconduct unless the reading was used to copy content in one's own work. In general, students should be encouraged to share their work with outsiders and even solicit feed-back.

In general, if you post to this forum, it is helpful to include your country and to more clearly specify your question and your situation.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

I'm in agreement with Thomas Schwarz.

In addition, kindly bear in mind, from a (info/cyber) security viewpoint, (finding out) that one has Access doesn't equating using Access. This is so when engaging **confidentiality** leg of the CIA of security.

The applicable Policy will be a *decider*.